# HTML and JavaScript. onSubmit never blocks the form from being posted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, onsubmit

I am building a webpage where I have people register an account. As a requirement for the webpage, I need to use JavaScript to validate their account information (username and password must match a specific password). If the registration pass the test, I redirect them to a php page that will store their information. If the registration doesn't pass the JavaScript test, I want the user to remain on the same page.

I've been fiddling with my code for a couple of hours now and I can't understand why it doesn't work. I removed everything non essential in the code until I could model whether or not the form gets posted when JavaScript returns a value of `false`. I searched for similar questions and found that problems are often that people forget to put `onsubmit="return function();"` in their form. Another frequent tip that is given is to use the `event.preventDefault();` function which I did. That is clearly not the issue here.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script> 

function registrationCheck(){
    if(event.preventDefault){
        event.preventDefault();      
 }
    else{
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
    return false;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="test1.html" onSubmit="return registrationCheck();" method="post" id="registration">
    Username: 
    <input type="text" name="username"> <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine when I use Edge to test it, but fails miserably with chrome 49.0.2623.110 m and firefox 45.0.1

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Comment: Who needs a plunker if you have Stack Snippets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would have looked in the console, you'd probably have seen some error about 'event' not being defined. The reason is that while IE (and Edge) use the property `window.event`, Chrome and most other browsers pass `event` as a parameter to the event handler.

So the line

```
function registrationCheck(){
```

should be replaced by these two lines:

```
function registrationCheck(event){
  var event = event || window.event;
```

This will declare a new, local variable named 'event', which gets the value of either the event parameter or (if it's empty) the event property of the window object.

Comment: I tested this solution and it works in Chrome but not in Firefox. Any clue why?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it doesn't like 'event'. You could try using a different name for the parameter and the local variable. Make sure to change it in the rest of the function too then. I haven't got FF on my laptop and can't test it right now.

Comment: I got it to work. The idea is that simply adding those two lines to the JavaScript doesn't solve the problem unless you also pass in the event as an argument when you call the function. Should have been obvious but I overlooked this. 

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the event to your `registrationCheck()` function:

```
function registrationCheck(event){
    if(event.preventDefault){
        event.preventDefault();      
    }
    else{
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

don't put the onsubmit inline in the form tag.

bind it via JS when you start

if you're using jquery:

```
$('#registration').submit(function() { registrationCheck(); });
```

then get rid of all the event stuff and just return false.  You currently won't ever reach the return false line because you're trying to access an event object you didn't explicitly declare in the function declaration like:

```
function registrationCheck(event) { }
```

if you don't need the event object for anything else than you're currently using it for, then just get rid of that stuff because you don't need to preventdefault or set a return value for the event if you're usng jquery.

Comment: not positive. could be that they wrote onSubmit instead of onsubmit, could be that they're not explicitly passing the event in the function declaration, alls I know is that binding via js will make your life 100x easier

Comment: If you are not certain, then why did you post the answer?

Comment: If you just bind the function like I showed and get rid of all the event stuff and simply return false, it will absolutely prevent the form submit. You have more errors in your JS due to accessing a non declared event variable that are preventing it from reaching the return false line.  the event.preventdefault() is not needed if you bind via jquery, so unless you have some other reason for accessing the event, you should just cut those lines.